# Javascript: adding methods using prototype descriptor

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
Sorter.prototype.init_bubblesort = function(){
  console.log(this.rect_array);
  this.end = this.rect_array.length;
  this.bubblesort();
}

Sorter.prototype.init = function(array,sort_type){
  this.rect_array = array;
  this.init_bubblesort();
}
```

The code above works as expected, but when I change the init function to:

```
Sorter.prototype.init = function(array,sort_type){
  var sort_types = {'bubblesort':this.init_bubblesort,
                'quicksort':this.init_quicksort,
                'liamsort':this.init_liamsort};
  this.rect_array = array;
  sort_types[sort_type]();
}
```

the init_bubblesort function results in an error saying this.rect_array is undefined. I'm trying to wrap my head around why init_bubblesort no longer has access to its instance's variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Call) to specify the implicit parameter (this).

```
Sorter.prototype.init = function(array,sort_type){
  var sort_types = {'bubblesort':this.init_bubblesort,
                'quicksort':this.init_quicksort,
                'liamsort':this.init_liamsort};
  this.rect_array = array;
  sort_types[sort_type].call(this);
}
```

Otherwise, there is no object associated with the init_bubblesort method.

For the setTimeout, do:;

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function(){sort_types[sort_type].call(self);}, 1000);
```

In the callback, this will refer to the window, so we create a separate variable (self), which will be closed in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! On a slight related note, if I do window.setTimeout(this.bubblesort, 80), do I run into the exact same problem? that is window.setTimeout(this.bubblesort....) doesn't seem to work either, and I suspect it's a similar problem.

Comment: LDK, yes you do. I'll update my answer to show how you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

The  reason why you are getting this error is that `this` referred to inside the functions are resolved into the object which the method is a property of.

In the first case this is the `Sorter` object, in the second it is the `sort_types` object, and of course, these are not the same.

The easiest way to do this would therefor be the following.

```
Sorter.prototype.init = function (array, sort_type) {
    var sort_types = {
        'bubblesort': "init_bubblesort",
        'quicksort': "init_quicksort",
        'liamsort': "init_liamsort"
    };
    this.rect_array = array;
    this[sort_types[sort_type]]();
}
```

As an alternative, `call` could be used to 'change' the context of the executed method.

And to answer the comment on the other question, if you need to defer the execution of the sort, the you can do this

```
Sorter.prototype.init = function (array, sort_type) {
    var sort_types = {
        'bubblesort': "init_bubblesort",
        'quicksort': "init_quicksort",
        'liamsort': "init_liamsort"
    };
    this.rect_array = array;
    var that = this;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        that[sort_types[sort_type]]();
    }, 80);
}
```

In this case the context is kept the same.

Answer (score 1):

[Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940073/javascript-adding-methods-using-prototype-descriptor/2940097#2940097) got your problem, but looking at your code, the `sort_types` object seems a bit *redundant* to me, if you are only using it to map a function `"foo"` with the prefix `"init_foo"`, you could do something simple this:

```
Sorter.prototype.init = function(array,sort_type){
  this.rect_array = array;
  this["init_"+sort_type](); // the `this` value will work without problems
}
```